# NullPointerException org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:37)

Tags: nullpointerexception, gradle, runtimeexception

Got the following stacktrace when launching gradle 1.1, anyone know how to resolve them:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.findLauncherJar(BootstrapMainStarter.java:37)
at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:28)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)`

I think the automatic unzip of the dists/gradle-1.1-bin/13d7lnhcrghv2i5e54el41jpgr/gradle-1.1-bin.zip might be failing. I checked permissions and that I have access to that directory.

If I unzip manually, then I get the following error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.1-bin.zip' contains too many directories. Expected to find exactly 1 directory.
at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:73)
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:129)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)`

I did a google search for gradle nullpointerexception and it mentioned the JAVA_HOME needs to be set for compiling, but I've already checked it is set correctly and been able to compile stuff with ant in that environment.

Comment: looks like it was caused by a rogue .svn folder sitting beside the gradle-1.1-bin.zip file. everything seems to work after deleting that folder

Answer (score 2):

I was getting exactly same error and I changed the version of gradle that I was using. Inside my gradle-wrapper.properties, changed version 2.4 to 2.2.1 and error is gone.